# Float in an html page

Tags: html, css

I have this code:

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8"/>
        <title> </title>
        <style>
            .name {
                width: 130px;
            }
        </style>
    </head>

    <body>
          <h1> Test </h1>

        <form>
                <fieldset class="name">
                    <label for="firstName">Name</label> <input type="text" name="firstName" id="firstName" required> <br /> <br/>
                    <label for="last_name">Surname</label> <input type="text" name="last_name" id="last_name" required> <br /> <br/>
                </fieldset>
                <br />

                <p>
                    <label for="textarea"> Free text </label> <textarea name="box_with_sizecss_and_placeholder" placeholder="Please type" id="textarea"></textarea>
                </p>

                <p class="range">
                    <label for="ran">Rank</label><br />
                        Easy <input type="range" id="ran" name="ran" min="1" max="8" step="1" /> Hard
                </p>


                <p>
                    <input type="submit">
                </p>
        </form>
    </body>

</html>
```

I want to make the the Free text and rank go next to the fieldset name (with some space) and the button to be in the middle of the page.

How can I make it work?

For the previous code I want to make this part to be next to the fieldset:

```
  <p>
                    <label for="textarea"> Free text </label> <textarea name="box_with_sizecss_and_placeholder" placeholder="Please type" id="textarea"></textarea>
                </p>

                <p class="range">
                    <label for="ran">Rank</label><br />
                        Easy <input type="range" id="ran" name="ran" min="1" max="8" step="1" /> Hard
                </p>
```

And the submit button be and the middle of the page.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask and then go to: http://www.w3schools.com/css/css_float.asp

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I did this really easily with some searches like "Put two divs next to each other" and "Center a div".

http://pastebin.com/SLQfGpQC